# Can a QToolbar be added to a QDockWidget?

Tags: qt, qt5, qmainwindow, qdockwidget, qtoolbar

I have setup my app to have various dock windows within the main window. I am also able to add a toolbar to the main window. However, I would ideally like to add the QToolBar inside one of the QDockWindow instances (or the QWidget that it houses) as the toolbar will be specific to that window.

Is this possible? I'm using a recent version of Qt, 5.10.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think it is possible.

1.`QDockWidget` can set a `QMainWindow` by `setWidget()` method.
  `QMainWindow` is made for just a mainwindow but it is not prevented from being used as a subwidget.

2.`QToolBar` can be attached to the main-subwindow by `addToolBar()` method.

3.The subwidget-mainwindow can naturally have its own `QToolbar`.

If you don't want to use `QMainWindow` as the widget of its `QDockWidget`,you can attach the `QToolBar` as a child widget of `QDockWidget`. But The toolbar is not movable as QMainWindow's.

I think you want to add `QToolBar` and use it as `QMainWindow`.
So I recommend that you set a `QMainWindow` as the widget of `QDockWidget`.And you attach any widget you like to the mainwindow after that.

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to stop the QDockWidget from growing when QToolButton items are dynamically added to QToolBar?

Comment: @AlanSpark In one word,I don't know.I also tried to attach a toolbutton into the sub-mainwindow toolbar.But It didn't happen.

Comment: "In a Word" may be better...I'm sorry.

Comment: Thanks for your comments on this, I really appreciate it.